# use "will" with "have to"

Tags: modal-verbs

Can we use "have to" to take about future without adding "will" or "going to"?

> Robert can't come out with us this evening. He **has to** work late.

or should we say:

> He **will** has to work late.

which one is grammatically correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> He **has to** work late.

This is correct.

> He **will has to** work late.

This is incorrect. However:

> He **will have to** work late.

is correct.

Comment: thank you, is there difference in meaning between "has to" "will have to"

Comment: **Has to** can mean in the present or the future. He has to breathe. He has to pay rent. He has to win this match to advance. He has to win three more matches to win any money. **Will have to** means in the future. He will have to pass a test before he can be hired. He will have to arrange for a ride home. He will have to explain his behavior before a review board.

Comment: *Will have to* introduce a notion of delay. "In one month, *he will have to* leave the family nest". In other word, if "he *will have to* buy another car" then he doesn't have to buy another car right now. Whereas "He *has to* buy a new car " means he needs a new car as soon as possible.